# Why do I get Win32Exception when running from TaskScheduler?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, win32exception

I get an exception ONLY when I run from TaskScheduler:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Application.Run(new Master());
     }
}

public partial class Master : Form
{

   public Master()  //  EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
   {

   }
}
```

Task Scheduler:

```
Run whether user logged in or not : Checked 
Run with highest privileges : Checked
```

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=The specified procedure could not be found
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeErrorCode=127
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WindowClass.RegisterClass()
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WindowClass.Create(String className, Int32 classStyle)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.MarshalingControl..ctor()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.get_MarshalingControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..ctor()
       at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor(Boolean autoInstallSyncContext)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor()
       at FssClient.Master..ctor()
       at FssClient.Program.Main(String[] args)
  InnerException:

Comment: I'd say you're on a hiding to nothing here - if you're running "whether user logged in or not" then you'll run in session 0 which is non-interactive. So you won't be able to show a `Form`.

Comment: When running from the Task Scheduler, your program doesn't get a graphical context assigned. Youi cannot create windows and other GUI elements through the scheduler.

Comment: Actually - I believe you can. I do this quite a lot. This WAS working but something changed overnight. I have other scheduled tasks with forms that are running happily.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while starting ```WCF```, Can anyone help ?